# How to place an appendix table under the appendix section?

Tags: tables, appendix

I have <Table 2> which I want to place under Appendix.
However, when I try the code below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt} 
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.125in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.125in} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.375in} 
\raggedbottom
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} 
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}


\title{\bf STAT 900:  PhD Research Skills \\ Fall 2020}
\author{The Author}
\date{}    
\begin{document}
\maketitle

.... %sections 1,2,3,4



\section{Conclusions}
\label{sec:section5}  
 
 I have already used a page.


\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\label{sec:appendix} 

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{crSSS}
 &        &             & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Average$\Big(\min\limits_{j = 1,\cdots, t}{C_i(h_j)}\Big)$} \\
  \cmidrule{4-5}
 & {$t$}  & {$P_{win}$} & {Random Search} & {Grid Search}  \\
  \toprule
  \multirow{4}{*}{$C_1$}
 & $10$   & 0.005 & 0.005 & 0.000 \\
 & $50$   & 0.005 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
 & $100$  & 0.003 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
 & $500$  & 0.003 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
  \midrule
  \multirow{4}{*}{$C_2$}
 & $10$   & 0.005 & 1.871 & 0.000 \\
 & $50$   & 0.005 & 0.918 & 0.000 \\
 & $100$  & 0.003 & 0.611 & 0.000 \\
 & $500$  & 0.005 & 0.174 & 0.000 \\
  \midrule
  \multirow{4}{*}{$C_3$}
 & $10$   & 0.005 & 0.001 & 0.000 \\
 & $50$   & 0.005 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
 & $100$  & 0.005 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
 & $500$  & 0.004 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table of Monte Carlo standard error for our simulation statistics.}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{STAT900bib}

\end{document}
```

It generates the following output:

[image]

Notice that the <Table 2> is not placed under the Appendix header.
How can I force the table to be placed under the Appendix header?

Thank you,

Comment: The `[t]` does mean "the table should go at the top of its page".  I would focus on the `caption` package mentioned in the second answer on that page.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. replacing [t] with [h] has solved the issue. Thank you again,